# What is **xyz meaning in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

I seen function called

```
def x(**xyz):
    print "Ok"
```

Now in this function what is meaning of `**xyz` i.e. `**` is for what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained in the tutorial, keyword arguments.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

> When a final formal parameter of the form **name is present, it receives a dictionary (see Mapping Types — dict) containing all keyword arguments except for those corresponding to a formal parameter.

Comment: And to be more specific, it means an arbitary amount of keyword arguments. It doesn't need to be a dictionary.

Comment: @J: Thanks for catching my goof.